# Unable to get List from response.body() from GET Retrofit Android

Tags: java, android, list, null, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to get List from GET request with retrofit. But whenever I try to access the value from the list value from the response.body() (which is successful to retrieve the data from database),the error is always index out of bound, which the List returns null.

I am trying to populate my RecycleView with all the data from the List. However it always return null and hence my RecycleView is always empty.

Below is the code for my service class:

`@GET("products/getallproducts") Call<List<Product>> getAllProducts();`

Class for retrieving my List and populate the RecycleView:

`public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`

`List<Product> proGet = new ArrayList<Product>();
    //some more codes here
    //some more codes here
    //some more codes here
    //lastly followed by the method createDummyData()`

```
public void createDummyData() {


    Call<List<Product>> call = restServices.getService().getAllProducts();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Product>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Product>> call, Response<List<Product>> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();

            productGet = response.body();
            //^^^this is where the problem is

           //class used for populating one section
            SectionDataModel dm = new SectionDataModel();
            dm.setHeaderTitle("trend");

            //class SingleItemModel is for adding single item into the section
            ArrayList<SingleItemModel> singleItem = new ArrayList<SingleItemModel>();

            //adding each item into the SingleItem array list
            singleItem.add(new SingleItemModel(proGet.get(0).status, productList.get(0).category));
            singleItem.add(new SingleItemModel(proGet.get(0).name, productList.get(0).productid));

            //populate the singleItem array list into one section
            dm.setAllItemsInSection(singleItem);

            //populate the whole RecycleView
            allSampleData.add(dm);


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Product>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


}
```

`

Error in logcat as such:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kennethlo.kickgoo/com.example.kennethlo.kickgoo.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`

I am desperate and hoping someone able to help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you assigning `response.body()` to `productGet` but then referencing `proGet` in following code?

Comment: yes, I need to use proGet outside onReponse(). I need to use proGet in another method which I declared

Answer (score 0):

First need to check your response size is greater than 0 (Zero).

```
if(productGet.size() > 0){
    //Code...
}
```

And also check the size of **productList** is greate than 0 (Zero).

Comment: proGet returned with size of 25 in the onResponse method, however when I call the proGet outside onResponse method, but still within createDummyData(), the proGet size returns with 0, and gives me index out of bound error. I wonder why.

Comment: when I try to add item in the SingleItemModel ArrayList

Comment: check the size of productGet and productList both are greater than zero

Comment: the proList returns 25, the proGet returns 25 when it is inside onReponse(); however when I called proGet outside onResponse(), it returns size of 0

Comment: proGet initialize in onResponse so obviously out side its value is zero without initialize it have no any object so

Comment: so I initialize proGet by `List<Product> proGet = null;` ?

Comment: what is the need of proGet out side onResponse

Comment: I need it for populating a recycleview, however it can't seem to work when I did it in the onReposne() method.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzTqvDPlz3zeMmJuTDdkd3ROWEE/view?usp=sharing)